# Simple thing about Index on sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with 3 column:

```
id, word, bitmask
```

I make a bitmask out of the vowels in the word, so I can quickly find every word that contains a certain vowel:

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE bitmask & 7 = 0
```

I have two questions.

1. Should I add an index? If that case, to what column and how do I write the query

I tried the code below, but didn't see any improvements in performance.

```
CREATE INDEX bitmask_index ON words (bitmask);
```

2. The "bitmask" column contains values from 1-256. Would it be a good thing to sort the "bitmask" column by value? In that case, how do I write the query for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Indexing is unlikely to help, because you are applying a function to the value before the search. Typically, this kills the effects of indexing.
2. Sorting bitmasks rarely makes sense, because bit positions in bitmaps do not correspond to something that is ordered across the rows (their ordering is associated with something inside the same row, e.g. the vowels in some word).